# Permission denied error dev C++

Tags: c, dev-c++

When I try to compile a C code again in DEV C++, the tool gives the error below. If I try to copy the same code in new file it works fine, but again I can't compile new code, needing to copy to another file again.

```
 Permission denied  ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Where is the code? Why are using such a bad and old tool like DevC++? Try to switch to Code::Blocks with a more recent MinGW package.

Comment: @david sure .. but still i need to know why IDE behaves like this :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The program is probably running. You'll need to kill it before recompiling.